# Dialogue on jmenuitem selection

Tags: java, swing, awt

I construct a GameFrame class that has a JFrame with a  `jmenubar` and add a few items to the menu. I separate the actionlistener class (implement my own and pass it as argument to the frames jmenubar) from the GameFrame for OOP reasons.

The problem is that when one of the `JmenuItems` are selected it should up a Dialogue asking the user to input a URL. But this dialogue is only created when the menuitem is selected so how do I **avoid** doing the following? (which isn't very OOP)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();

    if (item.getText().equals("URL")) {
        //create a dialogue 
        //get the input
        //pass it to something else
    }
}
```

I want to avoid the creation of swing components inside my eventhandler class and avoid eventhandlers inside my component class, but I see no way around it.

Comment: I don't see why is it not supposed to be very OOP. Could you elaborate on that? Anyway, Why don't you create your JDialog where you initialize the rest of your components and just make it visible in the actionPerformed and invisible as soon as you get the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `ActionLIstener`, and for the constructor pass a reference of the item it needs the reference (even if the object you put the listener is the same you need on the `actionPerformed()` method.

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    JMenuItem item;

    MyActionListener(JMenuItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // here you have the reference for the item. Printing the text:
        System.out.println(item.getText());
    }

}
```

The con of this approach is that you'll need one listener for each JMenuItem.

Comment: Also consider [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).